# SAS option value to macro variable

Tags: sas, macros

I want to store the value of a SAS option in a macro variable so I can reset the option, not to the default value but to what it was before, like this:

```
options mprint &prev.;
```

Does anyone know how to store the current option value in a macro variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
%let oldValue = %sysfunc(getoption(linesize));
```

You can look up the details of the SYSFUNC and GETOPTION functions in SAS's online documentation here: https://support.sas.com/en/documentation.html

It's worth spending ten minutes a day just browsing the docs, you will learn a lot.

Comment: The *reporting-option* `EXPAND` will simplify restoring the option.  `%let saveOpt = %sysfunc(GETOPTION(linesize,EXPAND)); … options linesize=250; … options &saveOpt;`

Answer (score 2):

If you are changing more than a few options, or don't want to deal options on an individual level, consider using `PROC OPTSAVE` and `PROC OPTLOAD`.  This form of options management is especially useful if you are working with a variety of macros and macro based frameworks within a single session.

```
libname options 'C:\Temp\MyOptions';

proc optsave out=options.held;

  options ls=max ps=max nocenter nodate nonumber orientation=landscape;
  %RichardForecastReport(date='01MAR2019')

proc optload data=options.held;

  options ls=128 ps=100 center date number orientation=portrait;
  %HenrikForecastCharts(date='01MAR2019')

proc optload data=options.held;
   … todays adhoc …
```

Comment: Thank you Richard, also very useful.